# How to get notified when an ios app review comes through?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, store

Using Ionic to build some apps for both ios and android.  Android I give it a developer email, and it gives me updates with the app store including anytime somebody sends a review through.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same for the ios app store.  I can login to itunes connect and see the reviews and have missed some negative reviews.  Is there some way to have apple send me some notification when a review comes through?  I guess I assume there is a way to do this. Just apple makes it hard to find it.

Comment: The app is mostly garbage, but you can get the iTunes Connect app in the app store and you will get notifications when your app changes states.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the functionality of the Apple App Store and not about programming.

Comment: I agree its not about programing directly, its about supporting code.  The problem is, it seems like there is no answer to this question.  Or it doesn't seem like Apple has a way to do this!  The problem is we are left to Apple to find this out, because any question about it gets closed, and the cycle starts over.

Answer (score 2):

The new [App Connect](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/) app that Apple released offers notifications now when reviews come in. This is available right now through the App Store.